# Powershell behind a proxy

Tags: powershell, proxy, nuget, docker-for-windows, docker

I have installed Docker For Windows and when I want to install posh-docker with `Install-Module posh-docker`, I have this error message :

```
AVERTISSEMENT : Impossible de télécharger à partir de l'URI
'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409' dans ''.
AVERTISSEMENT : Impossible de télécharger la liste des fournisseurs disponibles.
Vérifiez votre connexion Internet.
PackageManagement\Install-PackageProvider : Aucune correspondance trouvée pour les critères
de recherche spécifiés pour le fournisseur 'NuGet'. Le fournisseur de package requiert
les balises 'PackageManagement' et 'Provider'.
Vérifiez si le package spécifié présente ces balises.
Au caractère C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:7468 : 21
+ ...     $null = PackageManagement\Install-PackageProvider -Name $script:N ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument : (Microsoft.Power...PackageProvider:InstallPackageProvider)
[Install-PackageProvider], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForProvider,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackageProvider
PackageManagement\Import-PackageProvider : Aucune correspondance trouvée pour le critère de
recherche spécifié et le fournisseur de nom « NuGet ».
Essayez « Get-PackageProvider -ListAvailable » si le fournisseur existe déjà sur le système.
Au caractère C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:7474 : 21
+ ...     $null = PackageManagement\Import-PackageProvider -Name $script:Nu ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData : (NuGet:String) [Import-PackageProvider], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.ImportPackageProvider
```

In other words, Powershell doesn't access to Internet. In english :

```
WARNING: Unable to download the list of available providers. Check your internet connection.
Install-PackageProvider : No match was found for the specified search criteria for the
provider 'NuGet'. The package provider requires 'PackageManagement' and 'Provider' tags.
Please check if the specified package has the tags.
```

**What I have tried**

```
> netsh winhttp set proxy my_proxy:port
> netsh winhttp show proxy
```

The `netsh winhttp show proxy` command displays `my_proxy:port`. After that, I set my credentials like that :

```
> $webclient=New-Object System.Net.WebClient
> $creds=Get-Credential
> $webclient.Proxy.Credentials=$creds
```

Don't work...

I tried this :

```
> $ProxyAddress = 'http://myproxy.contoso.com'
> $ProxyCredentials = Get-Credential
> $null = & netsh @('winhttp','set','proxy',$ProxyAddress)
> $webclient=New-Object System.Net.WebClient
> $webclient.Proxy.Credentials = $ProxyCredentials
```

Don't work...

Next :

```
> Install-Module posh-docker -Proxy http://my.proxy.int:9999 -ProxyCredential $ProxyCredentials
```

And... still.don't.work...

When I test with `Update-Help` command, I have this error message :

```
Update-Help : Échec lors de la mise à jour de l’aide du ou des modules «AppBackgroundTask,
AppLocker, AppvClient, Appx, AssignedAccess, BitLocker, BitsTransfer, BranchCache,
CimCmdlets, ConfigCI, Defender, DirectAccessClientComponents, Dism, DnsClient,
EventTracingManagement, HgsClient, HgsDiagnostics, HostComputeService, Hyper-V,
International, iSCSI, ISE, Kds, Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive, Microsoft.PowerShell.Core,
Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics, Microsoft.PowerShell.Host, Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts,
Microsoft.PowerShell.Management, Microsoft.PowerShell.ODataUtils, Microsoft.PowerShell.Operation.Validation,
Microsoft.PowerShell.Security, Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility, Microsoft.WSMan.Management,
MMAgent, MsDtc, NetAdapter, NetConnection, NetEventPacketCapture, NetLbfo, NetNat, NetQos,
NetSecurity, NetSwitchTeam, NetTCPIP, NetWNV, NetworkConnectivityStatus, NetworkSwitchManager,
NetworkTransition, PackageManagement, PcsvDevice, PKI, PnpDevice, PowerShellGet,
PrintManagement, Provisioning, PSDesiredStateConfiguration, PSReadline, PSScheduledJob,
PSWorkflow, PSWorkflowUtility, ScheduledTasks, SecureBoot, SmbShare, SmbWitness, StartLayout,
Storage, TLS, TroubleshootingPack, TrustedPlatformModule, UEV, VpnClient, Wdac, WindowsDeveloperLicense,
WindowsErrorReporting, WindowsSearch, WindowsUpdate» avec la ou les cultures d’interface
utilisateur {fr-FR} : Impossible de se connecter au contenu de l’aide. Le serveur sur lequel
le contenu de l’aide est stocké est peut-être inaccessible. Vérifiez que le serveur est disponible
ou attendez qu’il soit de nouveau en ligne, puis réessayez d’exécuter la commande.
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Update-Help
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation : (:) [Update-Help], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnableToConnect,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.UpdateHelpCommand
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok.
The problem was that executing PowerShell as admin (with another admin user) was changing the user context and this admin user has no internet access...